# how can I escape the single quote and backslash in between using regex in java using String API or any regex expresiion

Tags: java, regex

How can I build a regex example that can escape single quote and backslash in a given string for example using java?

```
    input
  an'ish&nath$
    output
 'an\'ish&nath$'
    input
  anish\nath\
    ouput
 'anish\\nath\\'
    input
 an\'ish&nath$
    Output
 'an\\\'ish&nath$'
```

How can I escape the single quote and backslash in between using regex?

Comment: an\'ish&nath$ <------- Isn't the quote escaped here?

Comment: yes - he wants to escape `\ ` with another `\ ` and also escape `'` with a slash `\ ` (i.e. `\ ` --> `\\ `, `'` --> `\'` and thus `\'` --> `\\\'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `\\\\'` instead `\\\'`.

Comment: In my experience, it's best to place regexes in the context of the actual source code that uses them, especially when dealing with Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
     System.out.println("afa'adff\\asdf".replaceAll("([\\'\\\\])", "\\\\$1"));
```

Comment: it doesn't work for input String an\'ish&nath$ it shold print 'an\\\'ish&nath$' intead of it's prinitng 'an\'ish&nath$'

Comment: @anish: Give right input.`an\'ish&nath$` is equivalent to `an'ish&nath$`. so give `an\\'ish&nath$` to get expected output

Comment: Yes, if you used the Java string literal `"an\'ish"`, the actual string created was `an'ish`.  The string literal `"an\\'ish"` results in the string `an\'ish`.

Comment: @AlanMoore it's not a java string 'an\'ish&nath$' lets say it's a password expected output will be 'an\\'ish&nath$'